# How to read data in R when some rows contain commas as thousand separator and " flag and the rows without decimals don´t have flag

Tags: r, fread, read.csv, readr, csv-import

Im loading in R a csv (separated by comma) that has quotes **"** wrapping each row that contains a column with a value with decimals, and the particular value  is wrapped with double quotes **""** , the rows without this issue, have no **"** wrapping

the csv file looks like this:

```
YEAR,COUNTRY,VALUE_A,VALUE_B
2019,SPAIN, 2000, 300
"2019,SPAIN,""2000,54"",300"
"2014,SPAIN,""2003,223"",""125,057"""
2018,FRANCE,1900,280
```

Comment: With commas in the values, I would try to save the CSV as a tab-separated file and try importing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats a doozy... the best I could come up with is reading it as text and then using `gsub` to clean the thousands mark and double quotes.

```
# Read the csv as text, so we can run it through gsub
#
file_connection <- file("path_to_csv.csv")
text <- readLines(file_connection)
close(file_connection)
```

After reading the content of the csv as a string we can deal with the text "formatting"

```
# 1. Remove the comma as thousand mark
# There HAS to be a better way to do this regex but I couldn't remember
#
sanitized_mark <- gsub('(\\"\\"[0-9]+),([0-9]+\\"\\")', '\\1\\2', text)

# 2. Remove all double quotes
# 
sanitized_quotes <- gsub('\\"', '', sanitized_mark)

# Paste it all together adding a newline character after each element
#
sanitized <- paste0(sanitized_quotes, collapse="\n")
```

The resulting string can be read as if it was the content of a .csv using the `text` argument

```
df <- read.csv(text=sanitized)
```